# Automator-generated apps - Backwards compatibility

Tags: backwards-compatibility, automator

In my experience apps created with automator on Mountain Lion don't work on a Snow Leopard machine. The opposite isn't true though: apps created with automator on Snow Leopard do work on a Mountain Lion machine.

I'm creating a very simple wrapper around a command line executable and using cocoa seems overkill. I want the app to work on as many versions of OSX as possible though, so backwards compatibility is a concern.

Any thoughts on that matter? How can I ensure that my Mountain Lion Automator app is backwards-compatible?

Comment: Hi, I suspect without you telling us what actions or code you would be using. It is neigh impossible to answer your question with any sense of accuracy. Even though it is Automator you are using each action is going to rely on or use cocoa frameworks, shell code, scripting languages etc.. which have and will change. I also suspect that you will find it much easier to only worry about the current and last iteration of the OS.

Comment: It is a really simple wrapper around a command line executable that has been successfully tested on 10.6 and 10.8. The wrapper simply takes files as input and applies the executable to them.